# How to have Bootstrap's scss variables globally in Angular without importing theme every time in each component?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular-cli

I know there is a way to use bootstrap's scss variables in angular by importing the `_variables` file in each component's scss file and then start using that variables and there is lots of questions answered with this approach.

But I think this way is not a good way. Is there another way to import variables file or whole `bootstrap.scss` file to use mixins and variables without importing necessories each time in each component style file?

- I am using angular-cli v1.7.4

Comment: One way would be referencing it in index.html file. It will apply to every single page of your application.

Comment: Also if you use Angular Cli to generate the project, you can find style.css / style.scss. In there you can add your scss variables

Comment: @RukshanDangalla That doesn't work, I've tried before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Each component style is compiled separately.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3700

What you can do is specify the `stylePreprocessorOptions` in `.angular-cli.json` file so that you can import variables like

```
@import 'variables';
```

Instead of something like

```
@import '../styles/_variables.scss';
```

It's just more convenient, but you still have to include it in each component scss file

Comment: Also don't use the following names: `_colors.scss`, `_base.scss`, `_globals.scss`, because loader will try to load js, instead of scss.